# Avoid `goto` in a loop with "break and not execute code after loop"

Tags: java, goto

Goto must be avoided. But there are cases where you cannot avoid it, without ugly code.

Consider this case:

When an expression inside a loop, is true, loop must break.

If expression inside loop is always false, after loop end, a code must be run.

Is there a nice way to do this without goto?

```
for (int x = 0; x < input.length; ++x)
    if (input[x] == 0) goto go_here;  // this is pseudocode. goto is not allowed in java
// execute code
go_here:
```

My solution is this:

```
both:
do {
    for (int x = 0; x < input.length; ++x)
        if (input[x] == 0) break both;
    // execute code
} while(false);
```

Another solution is this:

```
boolean a = true;
for (int x = 0; x < input.length; ++x)
    if (input[x] == 0) { a = false; break; }
if (a) {
    // execute code
}
```

Another inefficient solution (similar to goto) is this:

```
try {
    for (int x = 0; x < input.length; ++x)
        if (input[x] == 0) throw new Exception();
    // execute code
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say? `goto` statements aren't allowed in Java. It is a reserved word, though.

Comment: Because in first case, break, breaks loop and does not execute code. In the second case, loop ends normally and code executed.

Comment: Do you happen to be Joe? http://thedailywtf.com/articles/do-while-false

Comment: I'm not 100% grasping the issue with break either, but I'll throw out the continue key word? Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
both: {
    for (int x = 0; x < input.length; ++x)
        if (input[x] == 0) break both;
    // execute code
}
```

A block statement is a statement, so you can give it a label.

Answer (score 6):

Put your condition in a method:

```
void yourMethod() {
  if (yourCondition(input)) {
    // execute code.
  }
}

boolean yourCondition(int[] input) {
  for (int i : input) {
    if (i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Or, if you want to use an `IntStream`:

```
if (IntStream.of(input).noneMatch(i -> i == 0)) {
  // execute code.
}
```